# How are divs styled with SCSS without SCSS file not being important to React component

Tags: reactjs, sass

So I am pretty new to working with SCSS and I have a client project (Gatsby JS) that I have to work on, that uses it.

I noticed that the footer is as below

```
.main-footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  }
```

And the component

```
<section className="main-footer">
    <h6 >Erreichbarkeit</h6>
</section>
```

The above code made the sections background yellow. My issue is that I do not understand how the component received the CSS from SCSS file as the component did not have the SCSS file imported

Can anyone help clear this up for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css files and also scss files are global. If any thing in the product imports a cass/scss file, the result is that the imported styles will apply to everything.

Is another file importing the scss file in question?

There are a few ways to fix this, two of them are

1.use https://www.toptal.com/css/introduction-to-bem-methodology to name your classes

2. look into css modules https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules. Behind the scenes, css modules add a string to all the classnames which makes it so styles are applied per file

Comment: You were right. The layout was importing the SCSS. I sorted it out now, thanks!